# How to use psql to copy rows?

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 dbs on two different servers.

How can I copy using psql all the missing rows from db1 table to db2 table ?
If this is not possible.. How can I copy the entire table ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a contrib module? If so, how about trying [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html). More information [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with psql directly using a single SQL statement because you cannot connect to two different servers at the same time.

The only way you can do it:

1. connect to db1
2. export the table contents using psql's `\copy` command (if you have access to the server, you can also use the SQL statement `COPY`
3. connect to db1
4. import the text file using `\copy` or `COPY` depending on where the input file is located